# JavaScript not working while submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am writing a HTML code in which there is a form with different radio buttons and the form will automatically be submitted on a click of any radio button and the form data will be submitted to a php file for database querying and the resulting data from the php file will be displayed in an empty div declared below. The problem is, javascript is not executing at all. When i dubmit the form via redirection i.e writing method and action, it is working fine. But as soon as javascript is used, it doesnt work. Moreover, if i write a simple javascript script, that is working. But this script is not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include_once 'connection-script.php';
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Competitions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
$("#queryform").submit(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                alert("In the query");
                var posting = $.post("previous-grades-student-script.php", $("#queryform").serialize());

                posting.done(function(data) {
                alert("In the success function");
                   var content = $(data).find('#showprevioussubmissions');
                  $("#showprevioussubmissions").html(data);
                });
            });

</script>


</head>


    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <link href='//www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

<body  style="background-color:whitesmoke;">

<div id="header" class="header" style="background-color:#6ccecb;">
    <?php
    $mail=$_SESSION['email'];
    $query="SELECT * from student where semail='$mail'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $filename=$row['studentid']."_dp";
    ?>
    <ul><p><a href="homepage_student.php">NAME</a></p>

        <?php
        if(file_exists('pictures/'.$filename.'.jpg'))
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="pictures/'.$filename.'.jpg" ><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        }
        else if(file_exists('pictures/'.$filename.'.gif'))
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="pictures/'.$filename.'.gif" ><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        }
        else if(file_exists('pictures/'.$filename.'.png'))
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="pictures/'.$filename.'.png" ><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        } 
        else
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="icons/user.png"><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        }
        ?>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="edit-profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="table.php">My submissions</a></li>
        </ul>

        </li>
            <li style=" margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="signout-script.php">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div id="compete" class="compete" style="position:relative; top:5%;">
    <div id="table-wrapper" class="table-wrapper">
    <h2> Selct a course </h2>
     <?php 
     echo '<form id="queryform" name="queryform" action="/" method="post">';

            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * from `student-course` WHERE studentid='$row[studentid]'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
            {
                $sql="SELECT * from courses where courseid='$row1[courseid]'";
                $answer=mysql_query($sql);
                $row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($answer);
                echo '<input type="radio" name="courses" value="'.$row2['courseid'].'" onchange="this.form.submit()">'.$row2['coursename'];
            }
            ?>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="showprevioussubmissions">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The above is my file. Plz Help.

**EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include_once 'connection-script.php';
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Competitions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>



</head>


    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <link href='//www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

<body  style="background-color:whitesmoke;">

<div id="header" class="header" style="background-color:#6ccecb;">
    <?php
    $mail=$_SESSION['email'];
    $query="SELECT * from student where semail='$mail'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $filename=$row['studentid']."_dp";
    ?>
    <ul><p><a href="homepage_student.php">NAME</a></p>

        <?php
        if(file_exists('pictures/'.$filename.'.jpg'))
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="pictures/'.$filename.'.jpg" ><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        }
        else if(file_exists('pictures/'.$filename.'.gif'))
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="pictures/'.$filename.'.gif" ><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        }
        else if(file_exists('pictures/'.$filename.'.png'))
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="pictures/'.$filename.'.png" ><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        } 
        else
        {
            echo '<li style="margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="#"><img src="icons/user.png"><p  class="usrname">'.$row['fname'].'</p></a>';
        }
        ?>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="edit-profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="table.php">My submissions</a></li>
        </ul>

        </li>
            <li style=" margin:-3% 1% 1% 0%;"><a href="signout-script.php">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div id="compete" class="compete" style="position:relative; top:5%;">
    <div id="table-wrapper" class="table-wrapper">
    <h2> Selct a course </h2>
     <?php 
     echo '<form id="queryform" name="queryform">';

            $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * from `student-course` WHERE studentid='$row[studentid]'");
            while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
            {
                $sql="SELECT * from courses where courseid='$row1[courseid]'";
                $answer=mysql_query($sql);
                $row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($answer);
                echo '<input type="radio" name="courses" value="'.$row2['courseid'].'" onchange="this.form.submit()">'.$row2['coursename'];
            }
            ?>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="showprevioussubmissions">
</div>

<script>
$("#queryform").submit(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                alert("In the query");
                var posting = $.post("previous-grades-student-script.php", $("#queryform").serialize());

                posting.done(function(data) {
                alert("In the success function");
                   var content = $(data).find('#showprevioussubmissions');
                  $("#showprevioussubmissions").html(data);
                });
            });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap your snippet in document ready handler or delegate it to document level or set event once element is available in the DOM, not before

Comment: copied the script just before the closing of the body tag. Still not working.

Comment: What means not working??? Is the event fired or not? Error in console? Etc... BTW, i don't get the purpose of `var content = $(data).find('#showprevioussubmissions');`? If `#showprevioussubmissions` element is part of data, then using `$("#showprevioussubmissions")` won't work because you aren't adding it to the DOM as i can see it

Comment: event is not firing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write jQuery code inside of $(function(){ /*code goes here*/ });

```
    <script>
$(function(){
    $("#queryform").submit(function(event) {

                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert("In the query");
                    var posting = $.post("previous-grades-student-script.php", $("#queryform").serialize());

                    posting.done(function(data) {
                    alert("In the success function");
                       var content = $(data).find('#showprevioussubmissions');
                      $("#showprevioussubmissions").html(data);
                    });
                });
    });
    </script>
```

Combine  section as single element.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Competitions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>




            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <link href='//www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
```

Comment: tried this, not working!!

Comment: You have used multiple <head></head> sections in your HTML code.
Multiple head sections are not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the code to add the event handler in the head of the page, before any forms exist. Therefore `$("#queryform")` will be an empty collection of elements and no handlers will be added. You should either put the code at the end of the body, or wrap it in a document ready, so that it will be executed after the form element has been created:

```
<head>
    <script>
    // call the function on document ready
    $(function() {
        $("#queryform").submit(function(event) {
            // code as before
        });
    })
    </script>
</head>
```